# button background color in button.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to edit the colour of a button when clicked.
here is my html and javascript

html:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" id="hello-1" value="hello">Submit</button>
```

Here is my JS:

```
//Name:buttons.js
//Created by: Jonathan
//Created on: 25/09/15.

'use stict';

$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('hello-1').click(function(){
       document.getElementById('hello-1').style.background = "linear-gradient(#337AB7,#215480)";
    });
});
```

I can't understand why it's not working. Any help?

Comment: Just add an # because its an id.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong. When you're selected an element by id with `jQuery`, you must add the `#` character before the id.

So instead of `$('hello-1')` use `$('#hello-1')`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hello-1').click(function() {
       document.getElementById('hello-1').style.background = "linear-gradient(#337AB7,#215480)";
    });
});
```

---

Edit:

Also when you are inside the click event handler you don't need to select the element again because `this` will point to the target element so your event handler can be as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('hello-1').click(function() {
        this.style.background = "linear-gradient(#337AB7,#215480)";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery why not use it to change css? Also you're missing the #.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
   var $button = $('#hello-1');
   $button.click(function(){
       $button.css('background', "linear-gradient(#337AB7,#215480)");
   });
});
```